# Using Entity Framework 6, why does the second SQL connection fail?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-6

I am new to Entity Framework. I inherited a website that is using Entity Framework 6. The website has two connection strings to access the database server. The first one goes to a shared database and determines which company database to open to get specific data. The website is hosted on Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8.5. The database is on Windows Server 2012 with SQL Server 2008 R2.

My connection strings look like this:

```
<add name="AuthEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Auth.csdl|res://*/Auth.ssdl|res://*/Auth.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SQLDB;initial catalog=SharedDB;persist security info=True;user id=##;password=#####;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

<add name="AssetEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Asset.csdl|res://*/Asset.ssdl|res://*/Asset.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=[SERVER];initial catalog=[DB];user id=##;password=#####;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

When the website is run on the web server, the first connection string (`AuthEntities`) connects to SQL Server and pulls shared data correctly (I can see shareddb data on the webpage after the error occurs). It then calls `GetConnectionString` to get the company database for `AssetEntities`. `MasterData` is a dll that contains the `.edmx` files and this connection string lookup. It's referenced in the website.

When the meets query is executed, I get errors

> EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.

Code:

```
using (AssetEntities context = new AssetEntities(MasterData.ConnectionString.GetConnectionString(companyid)))
{
        var meets = from m in context.Meetings
                    join l in context.MeetingLocations on m.MeetingLocationId equals l.MeetingLocationId into outerLocation
                    from l in outerLocation.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where m.IsDeleted == false
                    orderby m.MeetingDate.Year descending, m.MeetingDate descending
                    select new { m, l };

    foreach (var meet in meets)
    {
            //map the values to a new object
    }
```

`MasterData.ConnectionString.GetConnectionString(companyid)`:

```
AuthEntities authEntity = new AuthEntities();
Company company = (from c in authEntity.Companies
                where c.CompanyId == CompanyId
                select c).FirstOrDefault<Company>();
str = (company == null ? "" : ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AssetEntities"].ConnectionString.Replace("[SERVER]", company.Asset_Server).Replace("[DB]", company.Asset_Database));
```

This problem only occurs in our production environment. The QA environment has the SQL Server on the web server and this doesn't seem to be a problem there.

I've spent many days trying to find the correct keywords to use in a search for this problem and reading many articles trying to find a resolution. I'm at a complete loss.

Any help on resolving this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the server with its IP adress or fqdn (smoeserver.somedomain.com instead of someserver) in your connection string. That worked for us in a similar situation.